# TypeError: FormListView() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am newbie in django and i have a problem.
When starting the server, the following error occurs:

```
File "/home/user/Portfolio/web_project/web_page/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('',            FormListView(),     name = 'home'),
TypeError: FormListView() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I understand that I am not writing the requests correctly, but now I do not understand what exactly the problem is.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views      import FormListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',            FormListView(),     name = 'home'),
    path('success/',    Success(),          name = 'success')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.mail       import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.shortcuts       import render, redirect
from django.http            import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models                import Form
from django.views.generic   import TemplateView

def FormListView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = FormListView()
    else:
        form = FormListView(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            try:
                send_mail(name, surname, email, ['kirill_popov_000@mail.ru'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})

def Success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not *call* the function, but pass a reference to the view, so without the parenthesis (<s>`()`</s>):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',            FormListView,     name = 'home'),
    path('success/',    Success,          name = 'success')
]
```

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `form_list_view`, not <s>`FormListView`</s>.

Comment: Oh, and I spent three hours looking for this problem...
Thank you very much!